# Check if Bezier Curve is sub-curve of another Bezier

Tags: bezier, cubic

I want to check if a cubic Bezier curve is a sub-curve of another Bezier.

I think I understand basically how to do this, express the Beziers as two cubics, in x and y, then test if the cubics are scalings or translations of each other. If the scaling and translations match that tells us the curves are sub-segments of the same curve and gives us t0 prime and t1 prime of curve B in curve As space.

But I can't quite work out how to check the cubics for equivalence.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean you have two curves (say as coordinate sets) and you want to see if one of them is an (approximate) subset of the other? What have you thought of so far? Why do you think that will, or will not, work? Have you implemented this to test your idea? etc.

Comment: Say we take a Bezier Curve, and split it up using de Casteljau's algorithm. Obviously the result is a lot of sub-curves of the original curve.The question is how to go back, and recover the t values, and the fact that the curves are part of the same curve, given only their 4 control points.

Comment: So which of the two are you interested in? "See if curve B is a subcurve on curve A", or "try to reconstruct an unknown curve given known curves A, B, C, etc"? Because those are very different things, and your comment hints at you actually wanting to try to find an unknown "larger" curve given several known "small" curves. Which is a different question than what your post title asks about.

Comment: I don't think its reall all that different.

Comment: Then you may need to read that question again: one has a reference curve to test with, the other has no reference curve whatsoever. The difference is "can we *explicitly test* whether the curve is a subcurve" vs. "are we *guessing* at what the reference curve might even be". They are very different things, with very different approaches.

Comment: Let's say two curves are non-overlapping subcurves of another cubic bezier. By extending one curve to t = - infinity to t = + infinity, we can make the other two curves subcurves of it.

Comment: Okay, if you want to do that then my answer is still usable to you - literally do what you just said. Find out whether (1) holds, and if so, whether (2) holds. "Extending" the interval means you're now solving the general cubic polynomial, for the start and end coordinate, for each dimension (x and y). This is something any random solver library can do for you. Then take it from there.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've got the answer now. Take the two cubics in x and y for curve A, solve for the two end points, giving up to 6 potential t-values for each point. Evaluate A at all six points, and if the point is within tolerance, that's a t (due to numerical problems, x or y might be way out, but either x or y will be close to the real point). If both B start and B end lie on the curve, that gives us t start and tend in A's space. so t_B = scale * t_A + delta, with scale and delta known. Then substitute back into B's two cubic equations and test the coefficients are within tolerance.

Comment: you just summarized the answer I wrote four days ago, so I assume you'll hit the upvote button on that and accept it?

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm not quite sure what the etiquette is, whether to post my code (which seems to pass tests) or to close the discussion with your answer.

Comment: Standard operating procedure is that you accept an answer if it answers your question, and you upvote *any* answer that is useful to solving the problem (even if they're not a full answer, usually with a comment to tell them where it falls short). If an answer is clearly wrong, you comment on it (because no one benefits from wrong, or even unrelated 'answers'), and if none of the answers are correct, but you know how to answer the question yourself, you post your own answer and mark it as as the correct one (which you can only do after about a day).

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on the following comment:

> Say we take a Bezier Curve, and split it up using de Casteljau's algorithm. Obviously the result is a lot of sub-curves of the original curve.The question is how to go back, and recover the t values, and the fact that the curves are part of the same curve, given only their 4 control points

Short answer: unless you have an infinite precision machine, you can't.

So we're stuck with "error threshold" testing. Given a master curve A and a "hopefully subcurve" curve B, run through the things that need to be true if B *was* a subcurve of A:

1. If B is a true subcurve then its start and end point lie on curve A. So check if that's true, within some error threshold. If they don't, then B is not a subcurve of A.
2. If B is a true subcurve then the derivatives at B's start and end points are the same as the derivatives for the corresponding coordinates on A. So check if that's true, within some error threshold. If they're not, B is not a subcurve of A.
3. If B is a true subcurve then the second derivatives at B's start an end points are the same as the second derivatives for the corresponding coordinates on A. So check if that's true, within some error threshold. If they're not, B is not a subcurve of A.

If all of these hold, we can be reasonably sure that B is a subcurve of A.

Also, since we need to come up with `t` values in order to check whether a point lies on A, and what derivative of A is at that point, we already know the `t` values that define the interval on A that maps to the full curve B.

Comment: Thanks. I used a slightly different method but the answer certainly got me on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code.
(You can find cubic root finders quite easily)

```
 /*
        A = p3 + 3.0 * p1 - 3.0 * p2 - p0;
        B = 3.0 * p0 - 6.0 * p1 + 3.0 * p2;
        C = 3.0 * p1 - 3.0 * p0;
        D = p0;
    */
        bool CurveIsSubCurve(BezierCurve bez, BezierCurve sub, double epsilon, double *t)
        {
            int Nr;
            double tcand[6];
            int i, ii;
            double ts[6], te[6];
            int Ns = 0;
            int Ne = 0;
            Vector2 p;

            /*
              Take two bites at the cherry. The points may have slight errors, and a small error in x or y could represent a big error in
    t. However with any luck either x or y will be close 
            */
            Nr = cubic_roots(bez.Ax(), bez.Bx(), bez.Cx(), bez.Dx() - sub.P0().x, tcand);
            Nr += cubic_roots(bez.Ay(), bez.By(), bez.Cy(), bez.Dy() - sub.P0().y, tcand + Nr);

            for(i=0;i<Nr;i++)
            {
                p = bez.Eval(tcand[i]);
                if(fabs(p.x - sub.P0().x) < epsilon && fabs(p.y - sub.P0().y) < epsilon)
                {
                    ts[Ns++] = tcand[i];
                }
            }

    /* same thing of sub curve end point */
            Nr = cubic_roots(bez.Ax(), bez.Bx(), bez.Cx(), bez.Dx() - sub.P3().x, tcand);
            Nr += cubic_roots(bez.Ay(), bez.By(), bez.Cy(), bez.Dy() - sub.P3().y, tcand + Nr);
            for(i=0;i<Nr;i++)
            {
                p = bez.Eval(tcand[i]);
                if(fabs(p.x - sub.P3().x) < epsilon && fabs(p.y - sub.P3().y) < epsilon)
                {
                    te[Ne++] = tcand[i];
                }
            }

    /* do an all by all to get matches (Ns, Ne will be small, but if
    we have a degenerate, i.e. a loop, the loop intersection point is
    where the mother curve is quite likely to be cut, so test everything*/

            for(i = 0; i < Ns; i++)
            {
                double s,d;
                double Ax, Bx, Cx, Dx;
                double Ay, By, Cy, Dy;

                for(ii=0;ii<Ne;ii++)
                {
                    s = (te[ii] - ts[i]);
                    d = ts[i];

    /* now substitute back */
                    Ax = bez.Ax() *s*s*s;
                    Bx = bez.Ax() *2*s*s*d + bez.Ax()*s*s*d + bez.Bx()*s*s;
                    Cx = bez.Ax()*s*d*d + bez.Ax()*2*s*d*d + bez.Bx()*2*s*d + bez.Cx() * s;
                    Dx = bez.Ax() *d*d*d + bez.Bx()*d*d + bez.Cx()*d + bez.Dx();

                    Ay = bez.Ay() *s*s*s;
                    By = bez.Ay() *2*s*s*d + bez.Ay()*s*s*d + bez.By()*s*s;
                    Cy = bez.Ay()*s*d*d + bez.Ay()*2*s*d*d + bez.By()*2*s*d + bez.Cy() * s;
                    Dy = bez.Ay() *d*d*d + bez.By()*d*d + bez.Cy()*d + bez.Dy();

                    if(fabs(Ax - sub.Ax()) < epsilon && fabs(Bx - sub.Bx()) < epsilon &&
                       fabs(Cx - sub.Cx()) < epsilon && fabs(Dx - sub.Dx()) < epsilon &&
                       fabs(Ay - sub.Ay()) < epsilon && fabs(By - sub.By()) < epsilon &&
                       fabs(Cy - sub.Cy()) < epsilon && fabs(Dy - sub.Dy()) < epsilon)
                    {
                        if(t)
                        {
                            t[0] = ts[i];
                            t[1] = te[ii];
                        }
                        return true;

                    }

                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```